# C# Program Reading, Writing to Console, but Not to File

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am trying to alphabetize all the words in a text file using C#. I am able to read the file and fill the list properly. I am then able to iterate through the list and print to the console. However, while I am iterating, I am also trying to write to an output file. I cannot seem to pinpoint why the output file is empty while the console has all the words printed properly. The file sortedProposal.txt is created, but is empty.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IO_Practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //get the directory of the text file
            string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string cd = (Path.Combine(directory, @"..\..\"));
            string infileHandle = cd + "AModestProposal.txt";


            //print to screen for testing 
            Console.WriteLine(infileHandle);

            //Holds all the words in the story
            List<string> words = new List<string>();

            //Holds the words from one line
            string[] wordHolder;

            //Holds each line as it's read
            string line;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(infileHandle))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //print to console
                    Console.WriteLine(line);

                    //split line into array
                    wordHolder = line.Split(' ');

                    //add array to vector
                    words.AddRange(wordHolder);
                }
            }

            words.Sort();

            //Debug
            Console.WriteLine("Length of List: " + words.Count());

            //create the outfile
            string outfileHandle = cd + "sortedProposal.txt";

            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outfileHandle)) {
                foreach(string word in words)
                {
                     sw.WriteLine(word);
                     //Debug
                    Console.WriteLine(word);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking the obvious first: Are you 100% sure that you're looking at the right output file, and it's not being created in a folder you're not expecting (especially with the use of `..\..`)?  If you remove the one you think it is, does it get recreated when you run the code?

Comment: ^^ My thoughts exactly. The location of `..\..` will vary depending on whether  you run the program from the command line or an IDE.

Comment: The file is created in the file explorer on the same level as AModestProposal.txt. I can see this in the File Explorer and after I add it to the project in Visual Studio. There is a project directory, then a directory under it with the same name and in that directory are the source file, the text files I wrote, and bin, Project, and Debug files.